# TestRestTemplate with Spring-boot and Integration Testins

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-test

I am running a suite of IntegrationTests for my spring-boot project.  When I try to run a test on my REST endpoint, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.edelweissco.ofac.model.About] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]

"localhost" == entity.getLocation().toString()
            |  |      |             |
            |  |      null          null
            |  [Server:[Apache-Coyote/1.1], X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection:[1; mode=block], Cache-Control:[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma:[no-cache], Expires:[0], X-Frame-Options:[DENY], Set-Cookie:[JSESSIONID=DA7CDC16560B2183844B6ADDFC23944E; Path=/; HttpOnly], Content-Type:[text/html;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length:[550], Date:[Sun, 22 Jun 2014 03:05:11 GMT]]
            false
            8 differences (11% similarity)
            (loca)l(host)
            (nul-)l(----)
```

Here is my class under test:

```
@Controller
public class AboutController {

private static final String ABOUT = "about";

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( AboutController.class );

@Autowired
private ConfigurationSettings configuration;

@RequestMapping(value = "/about", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(Model model) {

    LOG.debug( "AboutController to about view" );
    About about = new About( configuration.getAboutVersion(), configuration.getAboutCopyright(), configuration.getAboutProduct() );
    model.addAttribute( ABOUT, about );
    return "/" + ABOUT;
}
```

}

Here is my test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = OFAC, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader)
@Transactional
class AboutControllerTest extends BaseSpecification {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationSettings configurationSettings;

    RestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Autowired
    private AboutController aboutController;



    def "test the actual endpoint"() {
        def url = "http://localhost:" + configurationSettings.getServerPort() + "/about"

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        when:
        def entity = new TestRestTemplate("user", "password").exchange(
                url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Void>(
                headers), About.class);

        then:
        entity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.FOUND;
    }


    def "testing url"() {
        def url = "http://localhost:" + configurationSettings.getServerPort() + "/about"

        when:
        def entity  = template.getForEntity(url, String.class).getHeaders()

        then:
        "localhost" == entity.getLocation().toString()
    }
}
```

I have the following Configuration for my MVC:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController( "/home" ).setViewName( "index" );
        registry.addViewController( "/" ).setViewName( "index" );
        registry.addViewController( "/about" ).setViewName( "about" );
        registry.addViewController( "/login" ).setViewName( "login" );
        registry.addViewController( "/upload" ).setViewName( "upload" );
        registry.addViewController( "/status" ).setViewName( "status" );
        registry.addViewController( "/search" ).setViewName( "search" );
        registry.addViewController( "/admin" ).setViewName( "admin" );
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName( "lang" );
        registry.addInterceptor( localeChangeInterceptor );
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale( StringUtils.parseLocaleString( "en" ) );
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {

        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames( "classpath:messages/messages", "classpath:messages/validation" );
        // if true, the key of the message will be displayed if the key is not
        // found, instead of throwing a NoSuchMessageException
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage( true );
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding( "UTF-8" );
        // # -1 : never reload, 0 always reload
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds( 0 );
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

I don't have any HttpMessageConverter configured because my project just uses Thymeleaf with models on the REST calls.  I looked for examples for using TestRestTemplate with integration tests, but didn't really see anything similar to what I am trying to do.

I would be grateful for any tips on this test, or a better way to do a full stack integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

It's more about the `View` on the server than about the test, I'd say. Your view might be rendering a perfect representation of an `About` object, but if it sets the content type to "text/html" then the rest template won't know how to convert it. What type *is* the response? Try setting it in your view.

Comment: Dave, Being new to Thymeleaf, I am not sure I follow.  In my html I have a "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>" but I don't think that is what you mean since my html is not being tested.  I added my MvcConfig to the original post in case you are referring to that.

Comment: I'm not really clear what you are trying to test. Your "about" view is supposed to be convertible to an `About` object according to the test. But if it's an HTML view how is that supposed to happen (HTML is not a natural representation for Java objects).?

Comment: Dave,  I was trying to find a way to test the REST endoint request/response.  If I was using JSON, I would test the string, but with Thymeleaf I thought I should test the model being returned with proper values.

Comment: Why do you need a `RestTemplate` then? You can just call the controller method directly.

Comment: I have been wondering the best way to test an endpoint so I know the url is handled, security is enforced, and the proper response is returned.  I don't think testing the controller directly would address that would it?